# Open buffer without loading ftplugins

Tags: buffers, plugin-system, filetype, ftplugin, edit

I have huge file and quite slow [plugin](https://github.com/jceb/vim-orgmode) (loaded by [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug)) for corresponding filetype. I want following:

1. Plugin is loaded by default
2. Option to fast open this file without loading plugin. Something like: turn all plugins off, load buffer, turn all plugins on.

**UPD.** In my case I want to copy some content of buffer `A`, then quickly and temporary read huge file to buffer `B`, paste content and save buffer `B` to huge file, and then return to buffer `A`. When I read huge file to buffer `B` I want all plugins to be turned off so reading is fast.

P.S. I've tried `:edit +cmd ++opt` but it doesn't help:

```
:edit +filetype\ off file.org
:edit +se\ filetype=off file.org
```

it seems that options apply after opening the file and loading plugins.

Comment: Does `:noautocmd edit file.org` work?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @D.BenKnoble. do you consider posting an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I came here to say `:noautocmd edit` but I see that @Ben already got it covered... Please post as an answer Ben!

Comment: @filbranden posted; needs more info, but I need to sit in front of my computer for that

Comment: @Ben Come to the dark side: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.droidvim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most “core” filetype features are covered by autocommands, so disabling them will have the effect that you want. But we only want to disable them when opening a particular file, so

```
:noautocmd edit {file}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the plugin. Seriously. "Huge and slow" = "trash bin". If you're brave enough then go and re-implement all required functionality yourself.
2. Remove/rename/comment out `ftdetect` folder/script (or use alternate extensions, so `ftdetect` never matches). Whenever you need the plugin do `:setf org` manually.

Comment: Plugin is good enough in most cases but in rare case it is annoying, so remove plugin isn't an option. I've updated question to extent use case description.